# Is there a neat way to count this?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

What is the number of  strings of length $n$ formed by the digits ${1,2,3,4,5}$ such that two consecutive entries are not same and $1$ and $2$ doesn't come consecutively ?

I tried inclusion exclusion but that is getting messy. Is there a neat way out ?

Comment: If two consecutive entries have to be different, then what does the part dealing with $1$ and $2$ mean?

Comment: @Stefan I mean string like 135423 is fine but 123542 is not as we have a "12" substring , similarly 213542 is not as it has a "21" substring

Comment: How is $135423$ allowed when there's the substring $23$ and two consecutive entries are not allowed?

Comment: @John11 'two consecutive entries can't be same' 23 is allowed and not 22

Comment: Neat as in "one-liner" – I don't think so. However, counting all the possible placements of "12" like "*12**" or "12*12" and so on, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @dtldarek But then i have to count the number of occurences of "12" in the string,which would have many subcases.

Comment: Are we supposed to exclude the strings $12$ and $21$ or just $12$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig both.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A_n$ be the number that end in $1$ or $2$; and $B_n$ the number that end in $3$, $4$ or $5$.
$A_1=2,A_2=8,B_1=3,B_2=15$.
Find a recursion for $A_{n+1}$ in terms of $A_n$ and $B_n$; and a similar recursion for $B_{n+1}$.